# How Useful are Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I understand a little bit about why they are good, but are they used in real world situation?

If so, how useful are they when creating nested transactions? What are the benefits?

For example (a VERY loose example), say I am creating a database with the purpose of helping others understand SQL (hypothetically).

So I need to write a script that would create the database, create schemas, create tables per schema, create sequences per schema, populate the tables with valid information and then end the script.

So in doing this I would break up my batches to run one after the other sequentially, eg.

```
 use master; go 

 create databse testdb; go

 use testdb; go

 create table tbl(XYZ); go
 insert into tbl (XYZ)   
 values (XYZ); go
```

So now, where in that block would I use transactions and why would I nest them?

Thanks in advance, 
I appreciate the help.

Comment: In the real world, I'm very glad that my bank uses transactions, so that money doesn't leave my account if the receiver has an error and doesn't acknowledge receipt.

Comment: If I ever saw a need to nest transactions, I would suspect that I was doing something stupid.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! for all the reading I can do, it doesn't always explain real world application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are a boon in cases where you cannot assure that all statements execute successfully. Basically, this is **always** the case.

There are **errors you realistically cannot avoid**: bugs, timeouts, deadlocks. if one of those happens you want all modifications you did to be undone and an error reported. You do *not* want to debug data corruptions problems that exist because some code only executed half way through.

There are other uses besides atomicity: You might want to isolate transactions, detect conflicting transactions, make conflicting transactions wait for each other and achieve mutual exclusion using locks.; Most trans are for DML, not DDL (speaking from practice).; Some trans acre *just* for reading a consistent time-invariant snapshot of the database.

Comment: See, that's what i thought that it would be but i wasn't entirely sure, studying up on it on my own leaves a lot to be desired. i appreciate it.

I thought there might be other uses but i wasn't entirely sure why.

Comment: Check out try and catch blocks in SQL as well.. makes it much more readable.

Comment: There *are* other uses besides atomicity: You might want to isolate transactions, detect conflicting transactions, make conflicting transactions wait for each other and achieve mutual exclusion using locks.; Most trans are for DML, not DDL (speaking from practice).; Some trans acre *just* for reading a consistent time-invariant snapshot of the database.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are used to ensure consistency in a set of DML (data manipulation language) statements. If something fails (for example because you are trying to create a duplicate key), the whole transaction is rolled back and you don't have, for example, an order header with no detail lines. You can choose to roll back manually with the ROLLBACK statement.

Another use for transactions is in database recovery. If the database crashes, you will normally have inconsistencies. The recovery operation will roll back incomplete transactions.

DDL (data definition language) statements such as CREATE TABLE normally execute in their own transactions - you don't want to leave the data dictionary in an inconsistent state.

In your example, the only transaction possible is around the INSERT. A transaction will be created automatically when the INSERT is executed. If your system doesn't have auto-commit turned on and you fail to COMMIT your insertion, your data will never make it into the database.

Nested transactions are used in complex situations where you might want to roll back an insertion into a child table and do something else (for example asking for additional user input) without necessarily rolling back the transaction on the parent table.

Comment: At least on SQL Server, DML is fully transacted.

Answer (score 0):

With create db, you can simply drop table if there are errors so you shouldn't need to use transactions but...

they are very useful when you're trying to maintain atomicity across multiple sql statements.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)